# Converting date YYYY-MM-DD (2015-11-09) to Friday 9 September 2015 from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I always save the date in MySQL like 2015-11-31 but now I am trying to show the date like this

```
Friday 9 September 2015
```

I found a way to show the current date and it workd fine like this

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");
?>
```

But how to do this with a date comming from MySQL?
Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime + http://php.net/date, **OR** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime()` has a second, optional parameter: a *timestamp* (ref: [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)).

The value you get from the database is stored as a timestamp. So just do

```
echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($valueFromDB));
```

Comment: It worked just so nice, thanks a lot amigo. I do not understand why some people come here just to vote down and gives poor answers instead of helping they just wanna distroy. Your answer is just perfect

Comment: @nicanica I think the reason you got down-voted was because you'd *almost* answered your own question. Visiting the documentation would've immediately revealed what you were missing. Have the PHP documentation in your bookmarks and consult it first before asking a question of this sort. There's a lot of good stuff in there you might be missing out on.